package error to install vscode
kc@kc-desktop:~$ cd Downloads
kc@kc-desktop:~/Downloads$ ls
'code_1.92.2-1723660989_amd64(3).deb'
kc@kc-desktop:~/Downloads$ sudo apt install ./code_1.92.2-1723660989_amd64\(3\).deb  -y
[sudo] password for kc: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'code:amd64' instead of './code_1.92.2-1723660989_amd64(3).deb'
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 code:amd64 : Depends: libasound2:amd64 (>= 1.0.17) but it is not installable
              Depends: libatk-bridge2.0-0:amd64 (>= 2.5.3) but it is not installable
              Depends: libatk1.0-0:amd64 (>= 2.2.0) but it is not installable
              Depends: libatspi2.0-0:amd64 (>= 2.9.90) but it is not installable
              Depends: libc6:amd64 (>= 2.14) but it is not installable
              Depends: libc6:amd64 (>= 2.16) but it is not installable
              Depends: libc6:amd64 (>= 2.17) but it is not installable
              Depends: libc6:amd64 (>= 2.2.5) but it is not installable
              Depends: libc6:amd64 (>= 2.25) but it is not installable
              Depends: libc6:amd64 (>= 2.28) but it is not installable
              Depends: libcairo2:amd64 (>= 1.6.0) but it is not installable
              Depends: libcurl3-gnutls:amd64 but it is not installable or
                       libcurl3-nss:amd64 but it is not installable or
                       libcurl4:amd64 but it is not installable or
                       libcurl3:amd64 but it is not installable
              Depends: libdbus-1-3:amd64 (>= 1.9.14) but it is not installable
              Depends: libdrm2:amd64 (>= 2.4.75) but it is not installable
              Depends: libexpat1:amd64 (>= 2.1~beta3) but it is not installable
              Depends: libgbm1:amd64 (>= 17.1.0~rc2) but it is not installable
              Depends: libglib2.0-0:amd64 (>= 2.37.3) but it is not installable
              Depends: libgssapi-krb5-2:amd64 (>= 1.17) but it is not installable
              Depends: libgtk-3-0:amd64 (>= 3.9.10) but it is not installable
              Depends: libgtk-3-0:amd64 (>= 3.9.10) but it is not installable or
                       libgtk-4-1:amd64 but it is not installable
              Depends: libkrb5-3:amd64 (>= 1.6.dfsg.2) but it is not installable
              Depends: libnspr4:amd64 (>= 2:4.9-2~) but it is not installable
              Depends: libnss3:amd64 (>= 2:3.30) but it is not installable
              Depends: libnss3:amd64 (>= 3.26) but it is not installable
              Depends: libpango-1.0-0:amd64 (>= 1.14.0) but it is not installable
              Depends: libx11-6:amd64 but it is not installable
              Depends: libx11-6:amd64 (>= 2:1.4.99.1) but it is not installable
              Depends: libxcb1:amd64 (>= 1.9.2) but it is not installable
              Depends: libxcomposite1:amd64 (>= 1:0.4.4-1) but it is not installable
              Depends: libxdamage1:amd64 (>= 1:1.1) but it is not installable
              Depends: libxext6:amd64 but it is not installable
              Depends: libxfixes3:amd64 but it is not installable
              Depends: libxkbcommon0:amd64 (>= 0.5.0) but it is not installable
              Depends: libxkbfile1:amd64 (>= 1:1.1.0) but it is not installable
              Depends: libxrandr2:amd64 but it is not installable
              Recommends: libvulkan1:amd64 but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.


FYI: You've provided a detailed post which contains clues in fixing the problem plus command that got that output which is very helpful, ONCE the release is known as deb packages are built for specific releases. Without that Ubuntu product & release detail, we're somewhat limited to generic details as we can't interpret provided pastes as we don't know what you're using (esp. for deb package issues)  Your issue could also be architecture related, but we were given details there either
